# $f$ is continuous, $f(0)=1$, $f(m+n+1)=f(m)+f(n)$ for all real $m,n$. Show that $f(x)=1+x$ for all real $x$.

Tags: proof-verification, functional-equations

In order to prove this, I had to back the proof up into a number of Lemmas. I am wondering if my method was reasonable, or if there was a more general or expedient path I might have taken? (I have left out all of the actual proofs with the exception of **Lemma 6**.)

## **Lemma 1:**

For any $a\in\mathbb{R}$,   $$f(a)=1+a \implies f(-a)=1-a.$$

## **Lemma 2:**

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\quad f(n)=1+n$.

## **Lemma 3:**

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\quad f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=1+\frac{1}{n}$.

## **Lemma 4:**

For any rational $\frac{m}{n}$, such that $0<m<n$, $\quad f\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)=1+\frac{m}{n}$.

## **Lemma 5:**

For any $a\in\mathbb{Q}$, $\quad f(a)=1+a$.

## **Lemma 6:**

For any irrational $x, \quad f(x)=1+x.$

**Proof:** Assume, for some irrational $x, \quad f(x)\neq 1+x$.

Say $f(x)>1+x$, then $$f(x)-(1+x)=t>0$$

and so, for any rational $a<x$ $$ f(x)-(1+a)>t.$$

However, by the definition of continuity, with $\epsilon=t$, for any rational satisfying $$x-\delta<a<x \quad\implies f(x)-(1+a)<t,$$

which is a contradiction. A similar argument shows that assuming $f(x)<1+x$ also leads to a contradiction, and it follows that $$f(x)=1+x.\quad \square$$

Comment: For lemma 6, you could use sequential continuity: for every irrational $x$, you can find a rational sequence $x_n\to x$ and $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)$.

Comment: I'd say the logic looked very good...hard to believe it could be greatly streamlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a translation $g(x) = f(x-1)$ the problem reduces to finding all continuous functions $g$, such that $g(1) = 1$, $g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$ for all real $x, y$. The second of these makes $g$ what is called an additive function; is a very standard functional equation which leads to $g(x)= g(1)x$ when **any** of the following additional assumptions is satisfied:

- $g$ is continuous at some point $x_0$ (you have that it is continuous everywhere, but it would have been enough to know it is continuous at any one arbitrary point)
- $g$ is bounded on some interval
- $g$ is monotonic on some interval

The proof, in general, proceeds exactly along the lines of those lemmas. But if you are allowed to use that a continuous additive function is always $g(x) = g(1)x$ as a theorem, you can "skip" all the lemmas.

Answer (score 2):

By setting $m=0$, we see that $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$ for all real $x$. Since $f(0)=1$ we have $f(n)=n+1$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$.

**Lemma.** $f(\frac n{2^m}) = 1+\frac n{2^m}$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb Z$.

*Proof.* If $m<0$ then the statement is simply a special case of $f(n)=n+1$. Suppose thus that $m\geq0$. I will use induction over $m$. Note that for $m=0$ the claim is still a special case of $f(n)=n+1$ and thus true.

*Induction Step.* Suppose that the Lemma is true for some $m\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$. Then for all $n\in\mathbb Z$,
\begin{split}
2\cdot f\left(\frac{n}{2^{m+1}}\right)&=f\left(\frac{n}{2^{m+1}}\right)+f\left(\frac{n}{2^{m+1}}\right)\\
&=f\left(\frac{n}{2^{m}}+1\right)\\
&=f\left(\frac{n}{2^{m}}\right)+1\\
&= \frac{n}{2^m}+2.
\end{split}
Between the first and second line I used the original assumption on $f$ and between the third and fourth line I used the inductive assumption.

It follows that $f\left(\frac{n}{2^{m+1}}\right)=\frac{n}{2^{m+1}}+1$. $\square$

Since $S:=\{\frac{n}{2^m}\mid n,m\in\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, $f$ is continuous, and $f(x)=1+x$ for all $x\in S$, it follows that 
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{f\equiv 1+x \text{ on } \mathbb R.}$$